# Unable to deploy twitter connector on WSO2 6.1.0

Tags: wso2

I tired deploying sample twitter connector on WSO2 6.1.0. Once the zip file is uploaded I get the message that file was uploaded successfully refresh the page to view the connector but connector list does not show the connector.

In the system log i see following error

TID[-1234] [EI] [2017-05-17 12:40:03,321] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer} - Deployment of synapse artifact failed for synapse libray at : C:\WSO2 Enterprise Integrator\wso2ei-6.1.0\wso2ei-6.1.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-libs\twitter-connector-1.0.0.zip : Error while extracting Synapse Library : twitter-connector-1.0.0.zip org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.extractSynapseLib(LibDeployerUtils.java:426) org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.createSynapseLibrary(LibDeployerUtils.java:65) org.apache.synapse.deployers.LibraryArtifactDeployer.deploy(LibraryArtifactDeployer.java:60) org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371) org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59) org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67) org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93) org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138) java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried building twitter-connector-1.0.0 and 2.0.0. 
Connector file for 1.0.0

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connector>
    <component name="twitter" package="org.wso2.carbon.connector">
        <dependency component="twitter_config" />
        <dependency component="twitter_search" />
        <dependency component="twitter_tweets" />
        <dependency component="twitter_trends" />
        <dependency component="twitter_user" />
        <dependency component="twitter_timeline" />
        <dependency component="twitter_direct_messages" />
        <dependency component="twitter_friends_followers" />
        <description>synapse library for twitter connector</description>
    </component>
    <icon>icon/icon-twitter-small.png</icon>
</connector>
`
```

Connector file for 2.0.0

```
 <connector>
    <component name="twitter" package="org.wso2.carbon.connectors">
        <dependency component="twitter_config" />
        <dependency component="twitter_friends_followers" />
        <dependency component="twitter-account"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-blocks"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-directMessages"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-favorites"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-help"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-lists"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-search"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-statuses"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-trends"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-users"/>
        <dependency component="twitter-tweets"/>
        <description>synapse library for twitter connector</description>
    </component>
    <icon>icon/icon-twitter-small.png</icon>
</connector>
```

Comment: Hi, Please share your connector.xml file

Comment: Why don't you try new version from store https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/e916c772-49b1-44ad-a051-539ee44dd673

Comment: Updated the post to include connector files. I have also tried the connector from store it does not work. I am seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation i found that the issue is related to WSO2 installation. Environment where i am not able to install twitter connector is setup using postgres database where if i use the OOTB WSO2 database i am able to install and use the twitter connector.

I hope this helps someone.

Thanks.